# C++ Visual Studio "Non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a ran in to this error (error C3867: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member) a couple of times. I know this question has been asked a lot of times, but I don't get why the problem happens and what I can do to fix it. I've read a lot of guides how pointers work and I've tried to play with the new knowledge, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

For this question I have made a simple code. Can someone help me understand why this error occurs and how to fix this code?

**Error:** error C3867: 'BankAccount::amountOfMoney': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "BankAccount.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    BankAccount bankAccount1("testName", 200.0);

    cout << bankAccount1.amountOfMoney << endl;

}
```

**BankAccount.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BankAccount
{
public:
    BankAccount();
    BankAccount(string name, double money);
    ~BankAccount();
    double amountOfMoney();

private:
    string name;
    double money;
};
```

**BankAccount.cpp**

```
#include "BankAccount.h"


BankAccount::BankAccount()
{
}

BankAccount::BankAccount(string n, double m) {
    name = n;
}

BankAccount::~BankAccount()
{
}

double BankAccount::amountOfMoney() {
    return money;
}
```

Comment: you need to review how to call a method

Comment: `amountOfMoney`is a function, so you have to use `()` to call it. Otherwise the compiler thinks you want the *address* of the function. `cout << bankAccount1.amountOfMoney() << endl;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the function call operator `()`. Change your `main` code to:

```
int main(){

    BankAccount bankAccount1("testName", 200.0);

    cout << bankAccount1.amountOfMoney() << endl;

}
```

Without the parentheses it tries to print the address of a member function, which it is not able to do unless the function is not a member of a class.

Comment: This is the output when I try to do that "-9.25596e+61". Shouldn't it return the value of the double "money" instead?

Comment: @Kasper - So what is the value of `money`? You don't set a value in the constructor...  *(And BTW, from a guy actually working for a bank, when you open a new account there is never, ever any money on it. You have to make a deposit. :-)*

Comment: @Kasper It did exactly what you describe: return the value of `money`. You never initialized the double so it will get an "uninitialized" value, which (on windows at least) usually looks like `0xCCCC CCCC CCCC CCCD` (64 bits). Hence the `-9.25596e+61`.

Comment: Ahh, of course! I totaly forgot to set the value from the constructor. Thanks all of you guys for explaining how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your member function, use brackets.:

```
cout << bankAccount1.amountOfMoney() << endl;
```

Comment: The second option is **wrong**.  You can't get a simple pointer to `amountOfMoney`.  It is a member function, and you can't generate a simple pointer to a member function.  You can generate a "pointer-to-member-function" *but that is not a pointer* (and the syntax is `&BankAccount::amountOfMoney`).

Comment: I'd delete this answer before it gets downvoted.

Comment: Second option would just print '1', given that the syntax would be changed to `&BankAccount::amountOfMoney`

Comment: Odd - my local compiler (CYGWIN 6.4.0) allows it, but godbolt doesn't. Ok, I'll remove that second option and re-word. EDIT: it's the -fpermissive option that allows it.